# :nth-child not working with achor tags

Tags: css, anchor, css-selectors

img class="preview" tags styled with padding-right, and .preview:nth-child(5) to remove padding-right worked fine, until I added anchor tags around image. I still have the padding, but the :nth-child() no longer works.

HTML
    
        AREAS OF STUDY /

```
    <a href="#"><img class="preview" id="nar_bu" src="images/bu/nar.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="preview" id="npr_bu" src="images/bu/npr.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="preview" id="pate_bu" src="images/bu/pate.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="preview" id="other_bu" src="images/bu/other.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.preview { padding: 19px 18px 0 0; }
.preview:nth-child(5) { padding-right: 0; }
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the selector on the anchor since it is now the nth child and the image is the anchors' only child

```
.preview { padding: 19px 18px 0 0; }
a:nth-child(5) .preview { padding-right: 0; }
```